# Graph isomorphic to symmetric group

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Show why the symmetry group of the graph below is isomorphic to $S_3 \times S_2$.
$S_3$ and $S_2$ are symmetric groups and $\times$ denotes direct product.

```
    *----------*
   /|\         |
  | | |        |
   \|/         |
    *----------*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  4----x-----2
 /|\         |
a b c        z
 \|/         |
  4----y-----2
```

I've labelled the diagram to show the degree at the vertices.

$S_3$ acts on a,b,c.

$S_2$ acts by flipping the whole thing over swapping x and y, and it is preserving a,b,c so we have direct product.

Comment: This assumes `a`, `b` and `c` are vertices, rather than parallel edges (as depicted in the question).  How does this preclude additional symmetries?  How do we show from this that the automorphism group is a direct product of $S_3$ and $S_2$, rather than, say, a semi-direct product?